# Issue with legend

Tags: r

I need to create many maps with the position of different ships in different days. I would like to use different colours for different ships but I have some trouble due to the fact that every day I have different ships.

Here is the R-code using standard plotting facilities:

```
# Create vector with all the ship names
shipname <- df

# Read every daily files

myfiles <- list.files(pattern="*.dat")
myfilesContent <- lapply(myfiles, read.table, quote="\"")

# Create the color vector index

z <- as.numeric((unique(df.knownSH$ship))
range01 <- function(x)(x-min(x))/diff(range(x))
rainbow(7)
cRamp <- function(x){
  cols <- colorRamp(rainbow(7))(range01(x))
  apply(cols, 1, function(xt)rgb(xt[1], xt[2], xt[3], maxColorValue=255))
}  

for (i in 1:length(myfiles)){

  # Create pdf daily file
  colnames(myfilesContent[[i]]) <- c("YR","MO","DY","LON","LAT","SHIPNAME") 
  ncol(myfilesContent[[i]])
  date <- as.chron(as.Date(ISOdate(myfilesContent[[i]]$YR, myfilesContent[[i]]$MO,                                       
  myfilesContent[[i]]$DY)),format = "day mon year")
  epoch <-with(month.day.year(date), julian(month, day, year, origin = c(1, 0, yrmin)))
  pdf(paste0(epoch,".pdf"),width=20,height=14)

  # Plot
  plot(myfilesContent[[i]]$LON,myfilesContent[[i]]$LAT,main = unique(date), sub = NULL, xlab = "LON", ylab = "LAT", ylim=c(-90,90),xlim=c(-180,180),cex=1.5,cex.main=2,cex.axis=2,cex.lab=2.5, col =  cRamp(z), pch= 17)
  map(add=T,col="saddlebrown",interior = FALSE)

  # Legend
  legend("topleft", legend=c(unique(myfilesContent[[i]]$SHIPNAME)), col=cRamp(z), cex=1.5,pch=17,border = FALSE)
  dev.off()
 }
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you are not using ggmaps as described  e.g. in http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-1/kahle-wickham.pdf

Comment: Maybe you would also want to add a bit of data (using dput(myfilesContent[1]) to the problem formulation. This makes answering your question easier.

Comment: So, your question is basically about how to hold the color of a given ship constant over multiple days, right?

Comment: Set the color vector's index sequence to the index sequence of your ship names.

Comment: For Peter Lustig, yes that is exactly my question. The problem I face is that with the above code the colours are messed up, but I want e.g. SHIP 1 to have the same colours over all the days where it appears. Many thanks

Comment: I think the problem is that there is no link between myfilesContent[[i]]$SHIPNAME and z